# Turn purchases off during vacations using WooCommerce is_purchasable and displaying a message

Tags: php, woocommerce

The aim and goal is simple. During vacation, turn off purchases and display a message. Problem is, this function messes up the product page and I am not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a theme error.

The message should not mess up the product page like this. **It looks like this now:**
[image]

**This is the full code:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'vacation_notice_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function vacation_notice_add_to_cart($is_purchasable = true, $product){

    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');

    $release_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2021-02-11'));

        if (strtotime($current_date) < strtotime($release_date)){

            $is_purchasable = false;

        vacation_notice();
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'vacation_notice', 5);
function vacation_notice() { ?>
    
    <div class="vaction-notice">We are on vaction and will return next week mondady.</div>

    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `vacation_notice()` is a hooked function don't add it inside is purchasable filter as you are doing, instead use the action hook part as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'vacation_notice_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'vacation_notice_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function vacation_notice_add_to_cart( $is_purchasable, $product ){
    $release_date      = '2021-02-11';
    $current_timestamp = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
    $release_timestamp = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $release_date ) ) );

    if ( $current_timestamp < $release_timestamp ){
        $is_purchasable = false;
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_vacation_notice', 5 );
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}

function single_product_vacation_notice() {
    echo '<div class="vaction-notice">' . __("We are on vacation and will come back next week on Monday.") . '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

---

You could even make your code a bit more modular and also display a notice in all other pages:

```
function on_vacation() {
    $release_date      = '2021-02-11';
    $current_timestamp = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
    $release_timestamp = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $release_date ) ) );

    return $current_timestamp < $release_timestamp ? true : false;
}

function vacations_message() {
    return __("We are on vacation and will come back next week on Monday.");
}

// Disable addato cart and display a message on single product pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'vacation_notice_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function vacation_notice_add_to_cart( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( on_vacation() ) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_vacation_notice', 5 );
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}

function single_product_vacation_notice() {
    echo '<div class="vaction-notice">' . vacations_message() . '</div>';
}

// Display a message everywhere else (not on single product pages)
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'general_vacation_notice' );
function general_vacation_notice() {
    if ( ! is_product() && on_vacation() ) {
        wc_add_notice( vacations_message() );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

Comment: Thank you and thank you for explaining. Just thanks.